# Best Way to Store XML in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, blob

I'm getting an XML API response, parsing the data I need, but want to store full XML response in MySQL for add'l data use later.

I intially stored the XML in a BLOB, but found special characters sometimes in values break the INSERT.

So, I first convert XML with htmlentities into a BLOB to keep original API response data integrity. Is this a good way to do it, or is there a better method?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show the code you're using to `INSERT` your xml into your table?  It's possible you didn't correctly escape the XML text.  Plus, XML should go into CLOBs (`text` data type). Base 64 encoding works fine, but bloats up your data a bit.

Comment: Of course - your using prepared statements and bind variables for this - this solves a lot of the problems of 'breaking' SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Properly escaped, any data can be `INSERTed` into a `BLOB`.  `htmlentities` is *not* the way.  For the `mysqli` API, use mysqli::real_escape_string.  For PDO use binding.

If you are running on Windows, be sure to fetch the data in binary mode, else CR/LF may get "fixed" during the read.

In theory `XML` should be UTF-8, so simply putting into `TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` should work instead of `BLOB`.

If all else fails, consider converting (in the client) the blob into Base64.  It will be 4/3 bigger.